# Change the encoding of file using apache comons io doesn't work?

Tags: java, notepad++, apache-commons-io

I'm trying to change the encoding of txt files using `FileUtils`, but after the execution of the function, I check the encoding of the file using NotePad++ , but there is no change in the encoding of the file.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;


 public class FileManager {


     public void changeFileCharset(File file) throws IOException{

            String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(file, "ISO-8859-1");
            FileUtils.write(file, content, "UTF-8");

    }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            FileManager fileManager = new FileManager();
            fileManager.changeFileCharset(new File("unknown_words.txt"));
        }

}
```

I also tried this function using the `BufferedReader` and `BufferedWriter`, but I get nothing .

```
 public static void transform(File source, String srcEncoding, File target, String tgtEncoding) throws IOException {
        try (
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(source), srcEncoding));
          BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(target), tgtEncoding)); ) {
              char[] buffer = new char[16384];
              int read;
              while ((read = br.read(buffer)) != -1)
                  bw.write(buffer, 0, read);
        } 
    }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

     FileManager manager = new FileManager();
     File file = new File("test.txt");
     File file1 = new File("test1.txt");
     manager.transform(file, "UTF-8", file1, "ISO-8859-1");

    }
```

Here is two pictures thats shows the encoding of the source file and the target file:

[image]
[image]

Is the charset check method using NotePad++ is bad, or what?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Encoding is not "encryption" (as you call it). Also, it is not always easy for Notepad++ to determine what encoding a file uses. For example, if all the contents are pure ASCII characters, then there is no difference between UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1 encoded files.

You should add some text containing words with French accents. Then look at the files after telling Notepad++ to read them as UTF-8 and ANSI, and see which encoding results in readable text.

Comment: Sorry about the encryption word, it's just a mistake